# Order saving error in backend: Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, magento, innodb

When placing manual order through admin of magento, I get this:

```
Order saving error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

I see a process in my phpmyadmin which is blocked:

```
SELECT MAX( CAST( SUBSTRING(  `request_path` , 15, LENGTH(  `request_path` ) -14 -5 ) AS 
SIGNED ) ) 
FROM  `cor` ....
```

I restarted the mysql, updated the innodb timeout... everything is working ok.

After some time, again - same query.

Anybody can please help me? Customers cannot add orders as well.

Comment: Please optimized  core_rewrite_url  table

Comment: You should consider increasing the lock wait timeout value for InnoDB by setting the innodb_lock_wait_timeout, default is 50 sec

Comment: I increased the 50sec to 360sec. Same issue. How do I optimize core_rewrite_url ? I think this is the cause.

Comment: I also truncated a big core_url_rewrite, reindexed, everything ok. The problem appears on import (on reindexing after import...)

Comment: SQL: SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`request_path`, 15, LENGTH(`request_path`) - 14 - 5) AS SIGNED)) FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE (store_id = :store_id) AND (request_path LIKE :request_path) AND (request_path REGEXP '^pantofi\\-femei\\-[0-9]*\\.html$')
BIND: array (
  ':store_id' => 1,
  ':request_path' => 'pantofi-femei-%.html',
)